# Hello i am doing a memory game with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello i am doing a memory game with javascript and i can't do the timer,i want to make a timer which start counting when I load the first time and ends when he  finds all pairs and i don't know what to do,if someone could help me
here is my code :

```
var array_cartas = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F'
var valores_cartas = [];
var idCartas = [];
var cartas_viradas = 0;

function iniciar_temporizador() {
    temporizador = 0;
    minutos = Math.floor(temporizador / 60);
    segundos = (temporizador - minutos * 60) + '';
}

Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function () {
    var i = this.length,
        j, temp;
    while (--i > 0) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = this[j];
        this[j] = this[i];
        this[i] = temp;
    }
}

function novoJogo() {
    cartas_viradas = 0;
    var saida = '';
    array_cartas.memory_tile_shuffle();
    for (var i = 0; i < array_cartas.length; i++) {
        saida += '<div  id="tile_' + i + 'onclick="virar_carta(this,\'' + array_cartas[i] + '            \')"></div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = saida;
}

function virar_carta(tile, val) {
    if (tile.innerHTML === "" && valores_cartas.length < 2) {
        tile.style.background = '#FFF';
        tile.innerHTML = val;
        if (valores_cartas.length == 0) {
            valores_cartas.push(val);
            idCartas.push(tile.id);
        } else if (valores_cartas.length === 1) {
            valores_cartas.push(val);
            idCartas.push(tile.id);
            if (valores_cartas[0] === valores_cartas[1]) {
                cartas_viradas += 2;
                // limpa ambas as listas
                valores_cartas = [];
                idCartas = [];

                if (cartas_viradas === array_cartas.length) { // 
                    alert("Parabéns acabou o jogo");
                    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                    novoJogo();
                }
            } else {
                function virar_para_costas() {

                    var tile_1 = document.getElementById(idCartas[0]);
                    var tile_2 = document.getElementById(idCartas[1]);
                    tile_1.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
                    tile_1.innerHTML = "";
                    tile_2.style.background = 'url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat';
                    tile_2.innerHTML = "";

                    valores_cartas = [];
                    idCartas = [];
                }
                setTimeout(virar_para_costas, 500);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "help me with my code"? Do you have any specific programming problem or error? Then please state it. What errors do you get? What exactly doesn't work. If you want us to write your code - forget it.

Comment: He stated what he wanted in the first line of his question @Alexander `"i can't do the timer"`

Comment: That's a little bit ignorant, don't you think @walther? You really should learn that not everyone in the world speaks English.  It doesn't matter what language a variable name is in, everything is still going to work the same.

Comment: I did not come here to upset anyone, I just came here looking for help to get away this game

Comment: Don't worry John, people seem to get annoyed very quickly on this forum. You've done nothing wrong

Comment: @JoshStevenson, not really. He came to English-speaking site where he expects a help, so it's a good practice. English is accepted as an "official language" safe to use (that's why we use English syntax, foreach, if etc.). I  really disagree that the language used for variables and methods doesn't matter, because when someone looks at the code, it must be immediately clear what it does. Sorry, but when I look at a variable in a foreign language, I can't figure it out without searching through the code. And also, I'm not mad, just giving him a polite advice to make it easier for him and for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval` to make a variable increase every second. Get it's value when finished to show completion time.

```
$(function(){

    var seconds = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        seconds++;
        $('input').val(seconds);
    }, 1000);

});
```

See my example here on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/o9h375od/)

At the same point you game is complete and shows the "Game Over" screen, make a new `var` called `finishTime` or something, and get the value of the `var` `seconds` which we are using in the above script.

So to put it another way, when the game is finished, do this:

```
var finishTime = seconds;
```

Comment: thank you! but how do i do now,to finish when i found all the pairs?

Comment: See my edit, you will just have to GET the value of the var `seconds` when the person finishes the game :) Dead easy

Comment: hey man,can you help me in one more thing?i can not transforme this code/this game in a 3x4 ,it is in  6x4,can you help me?